# How to get size of QSlider-handle?

Tags: qt, handle, dimensions, qslider

[QSliders](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qslider.html#details) are displayed differently on different platforms. How can I get the `width` and `height` of the `handle` of a `QSlider`, being it styled using [CSS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) or not?
I am only aware of methods to retrieve the `size` of the whole [QWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#details), but not the `handle`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a terrible way, which may not have to work correctly, but it still works:

```
QSize sliderHandleSize( const QSlider& slider )
{
    const QSize _minSize = slider.minimumSizeHint();
    
    switch( slider.orientation() )
    {
        case Qt::Orientation::Horizontal:
            return QSize( _minSize.width() - 1, _minSize.height() );
        case Qt::Orientation::Vertical:
            return QSize( _minSize.width(), _minSize.height() - 1 );
        default:
            Q_ASSERT_X( false, "sliderHandleSize", "Today is a bad day" );
    }
    
    return _minSize;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check [QSlider Stylesheet example](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2010/03/10/fancy-qslider-stylesheet/#):

```
QSlider::groove:horizontal
{
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    background: white;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal
{
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0,    x2: 0, y2: 1,
        stop: 0 #66e, stop: 1 #bbf);
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0.2, x2: 1, y2: 1,
        stop: 0 #bbf, stop: 1 #55f);
    border: 1px solid #777;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::add-page:horizontal
{
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal
{
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
        stop:0 #eee, stop:1 #ccc);
    border: 1px solid #777;
    width: 13px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover
{
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
        stop:0 #fff, stop:1 #ddd);
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal:disabled
{
    background: #bbb;
    border-color: #999;
}

QSlider::add-page:horizontal:disabled
{
    background: #eee;
    border-color: #999;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:disabled
{
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Edward, however I don't see how I would get the Dimensions of the Handles from the styling Example? I am not looking for how to **set** the `width` and `heigth` but for how to **get** these values?